# how to make key/value pairing for NSDictionary

Tags: json, sorting, ios6, nsdictionary

my Dictionary output is-
i want to fire insert command to insert this dictionary data to the sqlite database

```
(
    {
    iCardReceiverName = rp;
    iCardSenderName = madhusudan;
    isDeleted = 0;
    isReceiverSynk = 0;

},
    {
    iCardReceiverName = rp;
    iCardSenderName = mmmm;
    isDeleted = 0;
    isReceiverSynk = 0;

}
```

)

i want to insert this data into sqlite database.

here is my code-

```
                           NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                                      JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                      error:&error];


            NSMutableString *query = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into iCardUsers ("];
            [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];
            if (self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0) {
                NSLog(@"Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"Could not execute the query.");
            }


            for (int i = 0; i<[[jsonData allKeys] count]; i++)
            {
                [query appendFormat:@"%@,",[[jsonData allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
            [query appendFormat:@")values ("];
            for (int i = 0; i<[[jsonData allKeys] count]; i++)
            {
                [query appendFormat:@"%@,",[jsonData valueForKey:[[jsonData allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]]];
            }

            [query appendFormat:@");"];
            NSLog(@"qry : %@",query);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your data in sqlite db like in following example.
You can create a function with required parameters and insert data using the function.

```
-(void)InsertRecords:(NSMutableString *)txt{

    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movieData.sqlite"];
    const char *dbpath = [dbPath UTF8String];
    sqlite3 *contactDB;

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    NSLog(@"%@",dbPath);
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO myMovies (movieName) VALUES (\"%@\")", txt];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [txt UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually my problem is that,i  want only key/value pairing for  this dictionary data.i can not being able to do like that